# React, TypeScript &RxJS testing with Jest not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, rxjs, jestjs

I have a simple button component in `React` `TypeScript`, I using `fromEvent` method to translate click event to `Observable` wrapper of `RxJs` it is defiened `fromEvent(el:HTMLElement, eventType:string)` in RxJS

```
type NullableObservarbel = Observable<any> | null
type NUllabe = HTMLElement | null

    export const makeObservable = (el:NUllabe, eventType:string):NullableObservarbel => el ? fromEvent(el, eventType) : null;
type Props = {
    interval?: number // timee interval in millisecond
    label?:string
}

const Button:SFC<Props> = ({label}:Props) => {
    const btn = useRef(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        if(btn.current !== null){
            const observable = makeObservable(btn.current, 'click')
        }
    }, [])
    return <button ref={btn}>{label}</button>
}
```

As you can see `makeObservable` method,

1. I want to test this method with Jest --> if I pass proper `HTMLElement` and string as an argument it should return `Observable`
2. I want to simulate click event then I want to check `returned observable is working and subscribers of that observable are triggering.

But none of this test is not working as expected.

This is the test first one always pass even their is no el passed, the second one always fails.

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'
import Button, {makeObservable} from './Button'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'

describe('Observable', () => {
    it('should create observable', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Button />)
        const el = wrapper.find('button')
        const observable = makeObservable(el, 'click') // here i have the issue
        expect(observable instanceof Observable).toBe(true)
    })
    it('should create observable', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Button />)
        const el = wrapper.find('button')
        const observable = makeObservable(el, 'click')

        let _six = 0;
        if(observable){
        observable
            .pipe(map(e => 6))
            .subscribe(s => {
                _six = s
            })
        }
        el.simulate('click')
       expect(_six).toEqual(6) // fails always
     })
})
```

The biggest problem is I can't get `HTMLElement` type from `wrapper` so i just use `find` button and pass the result as an element, But

`expect(observable instanceof Observable).toBe(true)` this line is always passing event if I pass `null` as argument for `el` to `makeObservable`.

Please help me to test properly these scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with `testing-library/react` instead of using `enzyme` `shallow`, I have added `data-testid="btn"` attribute to your component then from the test I use 
`testing-library/react` to render your button then get your `HTMLElement` of your button I used this `testid` attribute.

It worked as expected in test and browser, pls check the source code.

Button.tsx

```
import React, { SFC, useRef, useEffect, useState, RefObject} from 'react'
import {fromEvent, Observable} from 'rxjs'
import {map, debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators'

type NullableObservarbel = Observable<any> | null;
type NUllabe = HTMLButtonElement | null; // more precise type
export const makeObservable = (el:NUllabe, eventType:string):NullableObservarbel => el ? fromEvent(el, eventType) : null;

type Props = {
    interval?: number // timee interval in millisecond
    label?:string
}

export type Result = [RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>, number]

// decoupled it from Button function body because you can test this later.
export const useEls = ():Result => {
    const btn: RefObject<HTMLButtonElement> = useRef(null)
    const [count, updateCount] = useState<number>(0)
    useEffect(() => {
        const el = btn ? btn.current : null
        if(el){
            updateCount(1)
            let _count = count
            const observerble =  makeObservable(el, 'click');
            if(observerble){
                observerble.pipe(
                    map(e => _count++),
                    //debounceTime(400)
                ).subscribe(c => updateCount(c))
            }
        }
    }, [])
    return [btn, count]
} 

const Button:SFC<Props> = (props:Props) => {
    const [btn, count] = useEls()
    return <button data-testid="btn" ref={btn}>Hello {count}</button>
}


export default Button
```

Button.test.ts

```
import React from 'react'
import Button, {makeObservable} from './Button'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'
import {map, debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators'
import {render, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react'

describe('Observable', () => {
    it('should create observable', () => {
        const {getByTestId} = render(<Button/>)
        const el = getByTestId('btn') as HTMLButtonElement
        const observable = makeObservable(el, 'click')
        expect(observable instanceof Observable).toBe(true)
    })

    it('should return false', () => {
        const observable = makeObservable(null, 'click')
        expect(observable instanceof Observable).toBe(false)
    })

    it('Should subscribe observable', (done) => {
        const {getByTestId} = render(<Button/>)
        const el = getByTestId('btn') as HTMLButtonElement
        const observerble =  makeObservable(el, 'click');
        if(observerble){
            let count = 1
            observerble
                .pipe(
                    map(e => count++),
                    debounceTime(400) // delay clicks if you want
                )
                .subscribe(s => {
                    expect(s).toEqual(6)// test just inside the subscription
                    done();
                })
            fireEvent.click(el)
            fireEvent.click(el)
            fireEvent.click(el)
            fireEvent.click(el)
            fireEvent.click(el)
            fireEvent.click(el)
        }
    })
})
```

This test is running as expected with simulated clicks and delays.

---

[React testing library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library)

Comment: thanks, is it possible to test my hooks also, you have mentioned `// decoupled it from Button function body because you can test this later.` in code, if it is possible how?